# How to call a javascript function on pageload in MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, pageload

This is my Java Script function:-

```
    function ValidatefuneralDate() {
    var today;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;  
    var day = currentDate.getDate();

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("en-US") > -1) {
        today = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
        var selectedDate = $("#Month option:selected").
        val() + '/' + $("#Day option:selected").text() + 
        '/' + $("#Year option:selected").text();
    }
    else {
        today = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
        var selectedDate = $("#Day option:selected").
        text() + '/' + $("#Month option:selected").
        val() + '/' + $("#Year option:selected").text();
    }
    if ($("#Month option:selected").val()==2)
    {
        $("#Day option[value='31']").hide();
        $("#Day option[value='30']").hide();
        if ($("#Year option:selected").text() == 2016) {
            $("#Day option[value='29']").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Day option[value='29']").hide();
        }
    }
    else if($("#Month option:selected").
    val() == 4 || $("#Month option:selected").
    val() == 6 || $("#Month option:selected").
    val() == 9 || $("#Month option:selected").val() == 11)
    {
        $("#Day option[value='29']").show();
        $("#Day option[value='30']").show();
        $("#Day option[value='31']").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Day option[value='31']").show();
    }
    if (selectedDate < today) {
        $("#lblFeneralDate").
        html('@Html.R(VirtualPath,"ValidatefuneralDate")');
        return false;
    }
    else { return true;}
  }
```

How can i call this function on page load time on browser? This function should call at the time of **Page Load** how can i do this?
how can a function bind with the page load?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use plain JavaScript as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  doSomethingElse();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in jquery api

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  ValidatefuneralDate();
});
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$(function() {
  ValidatefuneralDate();
});
```

this will get invoked  when the DOM is ready.

or you can use pageload event

```
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
  ValidatefuneralDate();
});
```

The pageload event is triggered after the page has been successfully loaded and inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Please tell me how ? i dont know syntax

Comment: But sir it gives the fixed value in Day DDL its not changing according to month

Comment: you question doesn't need answer for this question. right? please update your question first or post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery so just use the standard jQuery [page ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ValidatefuneralDate();
})
```

Or using the shorthand syntax:

```
$(function() {
    ValidatefuneralDate();
})
```

Comment: its working but here only 2nd if condition is running control is not going to else part

Comment: That's a bug with your code, either fix that yourself or open another question.